# C fork two children and pipe between parent and children

Tags: c, fork, pipeline

I'm trying to fork two children. Parent reads a line send to pipe. Child one reads it and write it to another pipe and finally child2 reads it. However, the output is always parent getting line. Thanks!

```
#define MAX 80

void child();
void parent();
void childtwo();
char * getli();
void printline(char *buffer, int count);
char * convertCase(char *str);

int pipe1[2]; 
int pipe2[2];
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  pipe(pipe1);
  pipe(pipe2);
  if(fork()){
    if(fork()){ 
      printf("1st\n");
      parent();
          exit(0);
    }
    else{
      printf("3rd\n");
      childtwo();
      exit(0);
    }   
  }
  else{
    printf("2nd\n");
    child();
    exit(0);
  }
}

void child(){
  char *buf;
  int count = 0;
  close(pipe1[1]); 
  close(pipe2[0]);   
  while(1){ 
  buf = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX);
  read(pipe1[0], buf, MAX);
  if (strcmp(buf,"quit")== 0){
    printf("Child is leaving\n");
    free(buf);
    break;
  }
  else{
    printf("Child: ");
    printline(buf,strlen(buf));
    write(pipe2[1],buf, strlen(buf)+1);
    free(buf);
        }
  close(pipe2[1]);
  close(pipe1[0]);
  exit(0);
  }
}

void childtwo()
{
  char *buf;
  int count = 0;
  close(pipe2[1]);
  buf = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX); 
  while(1){
    buf = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX);
    read(pipe2[0], buf, MAX);
    if (strcmp(buf,"quit")== 0){
      printf("Childtwo is leaving\n");
      free(buf);
      break;
    }
    else{
      printf("Childtwo:");
      printline(buf,strlen(buf));
      free(buf);   
    }
  }
  close(pipe2[0]);
  exit(0);
}

void parent(){
  char * buffer;
  int count = 0, done=0;
  close(pipe1[0]);
  while (done != 1){
    printf("parent getting line: ");
    buffer = getli();
    write(pipe1[1],buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);
    if (strcmp(buffer,"quit")== 0){
      puts("parent goes away");
      free(buffer);
      break;
    }
    free(buffer);
  }
  close(pipe1[1]);
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You have a memory leak in your child processes, you allocate `buf` _both_ before the loops, and inside the loops.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! But deleting it didn't fix the problem

Comment: Have you checked that all the system calls actually _work_? You should check what they return, if e.g. `read` returns `-1` then there was some error and you can use e.g. [`perror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/perror) to print out the error. You should do this for _all_ functions, even `fork` may fail.

Comment: One problem is that your processes are not closing enough file descriptors quickly enough.  The parent process should close the read end of pipe 1 and both descriptors of pipe 2 before doing anything else.  The second child should close both descriptors of pipe 1 and the write end of pipe 2 before doing anything else.  The middle process needs to close the write end of pipe 1 and the read end of pipe 2.  If you were duplicating descriptors (to standard input and output), you'd have more closes to do.

Comment: Your program is incomplete: `undefined reference to \`printline'`
`undefined reference to \`getli'`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it works fine for the first line, but not for any other.

This is because the first child process (in the `child` function) *exits* after it have read its input. You probably meant to put the `close` and `exit` calls outside the loop.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't even work for the first time. I moved close and exit outside the loop but got the same result